# Debug return value

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I can remember that I could see the **return value of a method** when I **debug** a **C++** code in Visual Studio 6.0.
Now I am missing that feature at **C#** in Visual Studio 2010.
Where can I see the return value or is there a cause for not showing it?

Edit1:
An example:

```
string GetFullName()
{
  return GetFirstName() + " " + GetLastName();
}
```

When I step (debugger) from row beginning with *return* to next line I would like to see the full name in a debug variable window.

Comment: You can call the method in the Watch window and see its return value there. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @sha No in C++ I could step out of a method and the return value was automatically listed in the debug variables window.

Comment: Oh, in such case I fear it's just not implemented.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This was added in Visual Studio 2013:

The return value(s) get displayed in the “Autos Windows” (Debug->Windows->Autos) and you can also use the pseudo variable “$ReturnValue” in the Watch and/or Immediate window to fetch the last function’s return value.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/27/seeing-function-return-values-in-the-debugger-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx

Comment: Would you mind describing the solutions in your answer? This would avoid navigating out of SO and it would give a static copy in case the link dies.

Comment: You can do the same for exceptions using the `$exception` variable.  Like how they're consistent in naming and case.  Great job.

Answer (score 4):

Simply when you debug the code, when return value has evaluated, do one of these :

1- type $ReturnValue in immediate window

2- watch $ReturnValue in watch window

[image]

Answer (score 3):

See this: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/555859/see-return-value-in-managed-code (and you can upvote it)

Also there is a comment there from a guy who developed a plugin for VS to support that.

Upd. Tried that plugin. Looks great for now.

Comment: Thank you. I will try the plug-in.

Comment: I tried the BugAid plug-in and it works. You need to set it to Full Mode for using the return view feature. It is a beta and the release is only free for open source projects and MVPs.

Comment: I just read at BigAid homepage (http://www.bugaidsoftware.com/purchase/) that the comercial license is not for free although it is only a beta. So I have to deinstall it because I cannot find any hint to a trial version for comercial users.

Comment: Yet another comment about BugAid license. The "About" dialog shows the sentence "BugAid is unlicensed and it is on day 1 out of 60 of its trial." So I think it is ok to use it as a trial for 60 days? I'm a little bit confused.

Comment: You have downloaded and installed the app from the official site. I don't think you are doing anything illegal unless you are downloading some unofficial releases.

Comment: Thank you. I downloaded it from http://www.bugaidsoftware.com/download. So I hope it is legal to use it the next 60 days.

Comment: @brgerner Hi guys, I'm the co-creator of BugAid. BugAid has a free trial for 60 days, which you can use freely for any purpose (commercial or otherwise). I hope you'll find it useful! Sorry for the confusion - we'll try to make it clearer on our website that it's a totally free 60 day trial.

Answer (score 3):

You can set a breakpoint on the line of the return statement with the method. Then right-click the breakpoint and select 'When Hit...'. In here you can select to display a message or run a macro. For this we'll print a message that will be shown in the Output Window. For example if you have following code:

```
public double ReturnValue()
{
    var x = 3;
    var y = 4;
    //x and y can of course be non-constant vars too
    return Calculate(x, y);
}

public static double Calculate(int x, int y)
{
    return x * x + y * y;
}
```

If you set a breakpoint on the line "return Calculate(x, y);", right-click it and choose 'When Hit...' and choose this as message:

> Value is : {Calculate(x, y)}

In this case the Output Window will display:

> Value is : 25.0

Hope this helps!

**Update:**

This also works for your example with the names, methods:

```
public string GetFirst()
{
    return "Bill";
}

public string GetLast()
{
    return "Gates";
}

public string GetFull()
{
    return GetFirst() + " " + GetLast();
}
```

Place the breakpoint on the return statement in the GetFull() method and do the same as before. The message-body now looks like this:

> Fullname is: {GetFirst() + " " + GetLast()}

And the Output Window will show:

> Fullname is: "Bill Gates"

Comment: Thank you. Is this solution better than writing the call in Watch window? I guess enter the call in Watch window is faster.

Comment: The problem with the Watch is that you have to put a breakpoint and while debugging select the method and choose 'add watch'. You can't right-click the method-call and choose 'add watch' as this gives an error in the Value of the watch. The 'setup' of my solution takes a bit longer but when debugging you have no more concerns. I just gave a solution for immediately viewing the return value of a method call as you asked... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't see the return value see the similar related question

[Can I find out the return value before returning while debugging in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268048/can-i-find-out-the-return-value-before-returning-while-debugging-in-visual-studi)

You can store the result into string variable so it will list in debug window.

[image]

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            Console.WriteLine(p.GetFullName());
            Console.ReadLine();   
        }

        string GetFullName()
        {
            string result =GetFirstName() + " " + GetLastName();
            return result;
        }

        string GetFirstName()
        {
            string firstname = "vishwanath";
            return firstname;
        }

        string GetLastName()
        {
            string lastname = "Dalvi";
            return lastname;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The additional variable is only an option for methods which are often debugged.

Comment: I just found yet another related question in *Related* list of this page at right hand side: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704268/getting-a-methods-return-value-in-the-vs-debugger.  It seems that SO search while entering question is not so good than *Related* list. I guess the ask-question-search does not care about tags field.