# How to see method return value which is not being stored with the debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

In Visual Studio 2013 how i can find out the value returned by a method which is not being stored anywhere.

Lets assume the methods are in a DLL which i don't have the source code so i cannot set a break point at the return line.

Example Use Case 1:

```
if(GetEnumResponse() == MyEnums.MyValue)
{
   // Do Stuff
}
```

Example Use Case 2:

```
var Response = (MyResponse)GetResponse();
```

In example 1, if im expecting the condition to be true but it is false, how can i use the debugger to find out what the result of GetEnumResponse() is?

In example 2, if the cast is causing an invalid cast exception how can i view what the result of GetResponse() is?

Comment: @Frédéric - I don't think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375551/debug-return-value is a duplicate. The OP can't see the source for the methods they're trying to see the return value of so they can't set a break point on the return.

Comment: @ChrisF, according to [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/27/seeing-function-return-values-in-the-debugger-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx) from the duplicate, the questioner should be able to observe the values returned by intermediary functions in the Autos pane, even if they cannot break at the `return` statements in the functions themselves. Am I missing something?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi. Hmm. Tricky. The question itself isn't the same and the main part of the solution doesn't help, but that aspect does. Not sure what the correct solution is.

Comment: You should look at [OzCode](http://www.oz-code.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to change how you call the methods to put the return value into a local variable which you can interrogate.

Case 1:

```
var result = GetEnumResponse();
if (result == MyEnums.MyValue)
{
   // Do Stuff
}
```

Case 2:

```
var result = GetResponse();
var Response = (MyResponse)result;
```

You can even leave this code in production if you want as it is functionally equivalent to what you have now.

Comment: Yes of course thats the obvious solution but in the case im debugging through a huge project. If i make changes like this everytime i want to see its value then i need to build and deploy to my test environment which takes about 10 minutes of my time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Immediate (Debug -> Windows -> Immediate) in Visual Studio.
Here you can evaluate expressions and see the result.

The return value of a function is displayed in the Autos tab or you can use the `$ResultValue` in the immediate window when the function has returned.

[See points 6 and 7 on this blog post about seeing function return values in the debugger](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/27/seeing-function-return-values-in-the-debugger-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx)