# In the Visual Studio debugger, you can view special 'variables' beginning with '$'. What are they?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

For instance, write a function such as:

```
void foo()
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception(@"whatever");
    }
    catch
    {
        int n=1; //put a breakpoint here
    }
}
```

When the debugger is on the line in the catch block, typing `$exception` will show the exception information.

Are there any more?  What are these things?  There seems to be no official documentation on them.  I've used `$exception` for quite a while, but was hoping there were others that, for example, would show the [return value of a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268048/can-i-find-out-the-return-value-before-returning-while-debugging-in-visual-studio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More of the special variables are described in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd252945.aspx).  There's also a [comprehensive list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff553485(VS.85).aspx) of the variables available in windbg - not sure how many are supported in VisualStudio though

Answer (score 3):

These are variables created by the debugger for your convenience. You get similar variables if you use the Immediate window:
`int x = 10;`

would result in $x in the locals window