# JetBrains: How to watch the return value of a function?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have a question about debugging mode in JetBrains IDEs (PyCharm, WebStorm, IntelliJ ..). Let's say I have a line in the code that looks like this:

> ....func1()...func2()...func3()...

Several functinos are called in the same line, and none of them is assigned to a variable. Now, I want to know what is the return value of each of these functions. I know the feature Evaluate Expression, but I don't want to use it, since it may invoke these functions again.

Do you know any way to find the return values of a function without assigning its value to a variable and checking its value in debugger?

Comment: Debugger shows function return values since PyCharm 2016.2

Answer (score 10):

As of PyCharm 2016.2, you can show function return values; to do so, you need to:

- Click on the *Settings* gear icon in the left-hand toolbar of the Debug panel
- Ensure that *Show Return Values* is checked

Then when a Return Value is present, you will see it listed under *Return Values* at the top of the *Variables* section of the Debug panel (and that information is retained while still in the calling function)

Comment: This is correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is possible right now but you could set breakpoints inside the functions itself.

Additionally you could add a "*Disable until selected breakpoint is hit*" + "*Disable again*" and join them with a breakpoint above the line you posted to make sure they are only called from this line.

Or simply refactor your code:

```
foobar.huey()
.dewey()
.louie();
```

and set line breakpoints as usual.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking also for this, and I can link you an answer I found, extending the answer of David Fraser: in IntelliJ, someone replied with screenshots to a similar question in this same site:
[java - Can I find out the return value before returning while debugging in Intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010362/can-i-find-out-the-return-value-before-returning-while-debugging-in-intellij#36570524)
Remember to put a breakpoint inside the function and step out :)

As said there (although it includes screenshots, much better than this) by the user [Birchlabs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5257399/birchlabs):

> On IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3: it's hidden inside the cog button of the
>   debug panel. Ensure Show Method Return Values is checked.
>
> IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3 "Show Method Return Values"
>
> Use the debugger to break somewhere inside the function whose return
>   value you'd like to see.
>
> step into function
>
> Step out of the function (or step over until you escape):
>
> step out
>
> Observe that the return value appears in your variables:
>
> observe the return value