# How to make IntellijIDEA debugger show return value of methods in a boolean expression?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

I approached IntelliJ IDEA from few months and I can't find a way to get (during debug) the return value of every methods in this code segment.

[image: code]

When i debug this piece of code in the context of a stack frame the debug show me only the value of `bToRet` (in this case `true`)

[image: debug]

but i need to get the value of each boolean methods without debugging every methods.

I found useful to use the *watches* tool and I add to watches every single method so I can see the return value for each method.

[image]

but this operation is too long when i need to watch a lot of methods so 
I'm looking for a better solution. So my question is:

**How to make IntellijIDEA debugger show return value of every method in a condition expression without adding it to watches or without evaluate the expression?** Or Is there a keybind to add quickly on watches the methods or evaluate expression?

**[Edit]**

I also used the *evaluate expression* tool.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar: [*Can I find out the return value before returning while debugging in Intellij?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5010362/642706)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place a breakpoint in the `if` block and `alt-click` any statement to get a quick result.

[image]