# Can I find out the return value before returning while debugging in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

There are features `Watch method return values` or `Show Method Return Values` in IntelliJ (source: [Can I find out the return value before returning while debugging in Intellij?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010362/can-i-find-out-the-return-value-before-returning-while-debugging-in-intellij)). Does VS Code have similar feature for all languages (especially Java)?

Answer (score 0):

After months of searching, include using OpenAI and Google Bard, there is no similar extension like `Watch method return values` or `Show Method Return Values` in IntelliJ for VS Code. The nearest is

1. Set the breakpoint at the return statement.
2. When the breakpoint is hit, copy the statement, without return keyword.
3. Paste to Debug Console (Ctrl+Shift+Y to open in Windows).