# How to know function return value during debugging in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I want to know returning value of FunctionY without assigning it to variable during debugging is it possible ???

```
public string FunctionX()
{
   return FunctionY("some parameter");
}
public bool MainFunction()
{
   if (FunctionX() == "Value")
      return true;
   else
      return false;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I find out the return value before returning while debugging in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268048/can-i-find-out-the-return-value-before-returning-while-debugging-in-visual-studi)

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint on the line with the `if` - once hit, go to the next line.

It will be either of the two return statements.

---

It is **not** possible to simply see the return value of the function, as the answers to [Can I find out the return value before returning while debugging in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268048/can-i-find-out-the-return-value-before-returning-while-debugging-in-visual-studi) say.