# Is it possible to inspect the return value of a function that is not saved?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

This is a slight variation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268048/can-i-find-out-the-return-value-before-returning-while-debugging-in-visual-studi). If I have a function that performs an action that returns a value but I did not capture that value in a variable, is there any way I can get that value while stepping through with the debugger without running the function a 2nd time in the immediate window?

A practical example

```
using (SqlConnection cnSqlConnect = OpenConnection(ConnectionString))
using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(command, cnSqlConnect))
{
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Is there any way to get the value of `sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` without running it twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is!

1. Break on the function before it executes.
2. From the Command Window run the line of code you stopped on, prepended with a `?` to view the results. Like this: `? sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`
3. Manually drag the yellow pointer showing the next line of code to be executed down to the next line, skpping over the code that you ran in the command window.

This will have the effect of only executing your code once and will let you view the result.

For more information see the [Basics of using the Command Window](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/seealso/archive/2011/01/25/using-the-command-window-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx).

Comment: Your answer to my Dup gave me the idea for the solution to this problem :). It can't be used for the other problem because running the command has side effects, but if you are not returning and just throwing the value away, your solution works. (If you make an answer I will upvote yours and delete mine)