# Making a method return an arbitrary value while debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So let's say I'm debugging the following method in a C# program:

```
int MyMethod()
{
   return 0;
}
```

Is there any way (for example in the watch window?) to execute a statement that will make MyMethod return the value of 1? Or alter the returned value in any way not touching the code at all? (This means that adding int i = 0; return i; and then changing the value of i with the debugger is not an option)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is the BIG picture?

Comment: Exactly what I said. Make the debugger return an arbitrary value at runtime when the code says different. The big picture is that I can't change the code at all, but I can step through it. Can't add an intermediate variable say int i = 0; return i; and then modify i at runtime.

Comment: You can barely read return value - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268048/can-i-find-out-the-return-value-before-returning-while-debugging-in-visual-studi, one of the answers there shows how sometimes you can [change it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13132495/477420).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the signpost might point to the wrong duplicate (as the referenced one does not really address C#).