# Can breakpoint actions print the return value?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

I'm attempting to output the values returned by a method using a breakpoint action. The method contains multiple non-identical return statements, similar to this example:

```
double Foo(int bar, int baz)
{
    if (bar < 0)
        return Math.Sqrt((double)(baz - bar) * (baz - bar));

    if (bar % baz == 0)
    {
        if (baz == 3)
        {
            return bar / 2 * baz;
        }
        else
        {
            return Math.Pow(bar, baz);
        }
    }

    return Math.Log(baz, bar);
}
```

I'm looking for a way to output the return value without resorting to refactoring the method such that it stores the value in a variable, or putting a breakpoint on each return statement and having to write an individual action for each one.

The accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268048/can-i-find-out-the-return-value-before-returning-while-debugging-in-visual-studi) shows that it's possible to inspect the return value using the `$ReturnValue` keyword in the Immediate Window just before leaving the method.

The below image illustrates what I'd like to accomplish.

[image]

This won't work of course, and print:

> DEBUG Result of Foo("1", false) = error CS0103: The name "$ReturnValue" does not exist in the current context.

While there are several keywords available, like `$CALLER` or `$TNAME`, I haven't found anything that will yield the return value.

Is it possible to print a return value in a single breakpoint action?

Comment: @SeM Output them in the Output Window

Comment: Why just not to use `Debug.Print(yourMethodReturnValue)` on calling part?

Comment: There's only a limited list of key word (as $FUNCTION) you can return with breakpoint, and $ReturnValue isn't one, your error message comes from here. For output the return value of your function, I would use a simple Console.WriteLine() before returning the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put breakpoint after your method call and add breakpoint action like so:

```
static int Sum(int a, int b) => a + b;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int sum = Sum(1,2);
    {} // add breakpoint here
}
```

and action code:

```
Sum returned {x}.
```

it will print in output window:

> Sum returned 3.

OR

Put breakpoint to your method's return part (in this case `a + b`) and add action like

```
$FUNCTION result is {a + b}
```

the output will be:

> MyApp.Program.Sum(int, int) result is 3

Comment: The method is being called from several places all over the project; I would prefer to have a way to handle all calls without adding code to each call site.

Comment: @waldrumpus I've added another method too.

Comment: Thanks for your update; the second method will require me to write an individual action for each return statement. Can this be avoided? See my update for an example.